# Question about resources for development in scope?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask question explaining my project which is based on information security and ask for advises and resources to learn from.

Is it in scope or will be closed ?

Answer (score 5):

It will be closed. Questions asking about where to find products, services, links, books, anything where the answers are purely links to outside resources are off topic.

Comment: It's not about purely linking to outside resources. I also wish to seek advice on how to proceed on my project and point me to resources.

Comment: @Rahul If not asking for outside resources, then yes, it would be on-topic ***if*** the questions are security-related and not programming or project-related.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question my project is based on Information security. But I don't know where to start. I know little know how of things but that's not enough. Am looking mainly for advice but links to resources is a plus.

Comment: @Rahul I'm trying to point out a fine line here: questions about *security* are on-topic. If your project is about security, but you are asking "project" questions, then that's off-topic. Questions have to be *about security*. For instance, you want to code your own anti-virus and you are asking what language to program that in: not a security question. "I want to do a project in X, but I don't know where to start": not a security question.

Comment: Acknowledged. Thanks for your time. P.S: Where can I ask such questions ?

Comment: @Rahul programming questions do to StackOverflow. You have not described your question so  I cannot help further

Comment: My project is a simple Web Application Scanner which should be able to detect XSS with low false positive rate. I plan to add features like proxy and fuzzer. But I don't know what programming concepts and technologies to use.

Answer (score 2):

I think overall it's a great thing to talk about, but the question isn't well suited to this site.  This site is designed for questions that can have one relatively short and correct answer.  As such, there's several obstacles to your proposal:

- Your idea sounds complex, and complex questions aren't a good fit.  First, complex questions almost never have just one right answer.  Second, a question with ten ideas and ten issues is much worse than a question with one idea and one issue.
- Submitting an idea for feedback rarely works well on this site.  I'll do you the favor of assuming you're a serious student or professional who understands fundamental security concepts and isn't trying to reinvent standard industry technologies (there are a lot of very naive and unprofessional proposals on this site).  Even if your idea is good, improving it would be an extended discussion or reviews and re-reviews.  That kind of back-and-forth dialogue isn't well suited for a question and answer site
- As Shroeder pointed out, questions about programming (i.e. hosting solutions, languages, error messages, code issues, etc.) are not on topic here. Questions about security (blacklists vs whitelists, XSS formats, security policies) are on-topic.  Questions about techniques, technologies, and tools fall into a grey area.  Questions here should be the kind a CISO or pen-tester would answer, not the kind a software engineer at Kapersky would answer.
- As Shroeder pointed out, asking for recommdenations is not on topic because it's hard for those to have a "correct" answer and they're not useful to others because the answer to the question would change every few years.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped.